# Include image in a Polymer element

Tags: polymer

new guy here, even tho i have been using this website a lot as a silent reader and it always helped me out so far but this time i didn't find what i was looking for. Right now i am trying to write a polymer element which should include a picture.

So this is the file structure of this element:

```
├── images
│   └── image.png
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── polymer-image.js
└── polymer.json
```

relevant code of my polymer-image.js:

```
<div id="container">
        <img src="images/image.png" width="300" height="300">
      </div>
```

content of this compoment's polymer.json (trying to include this image somehow):

```
{
  "sources": [
    "images/**/*",
    "/images/**/*"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "images/**/*",
    "/images/**/*"
  ],
  "npm": true,
  "lint": {
    "rules": [
      "polymer-3"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am installing this component in my application via npm and including it in my-view.js with an ES6 `import` The problem i have is that this image isn't contained in the build (`es6-unbundled` folder in my case) made by `polymer build` on application level. 
The file structure of my build looks like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── node_modules
│   ├── @myName
│   │   ├── my-polymer-image
│   │   │   └── polymer-image.js
│   ├── @polymer

## a lot of other stuff here##

├── push-manifest.json
├── service-worker.js
└── src
    ├── my-app.js
    └── views
        ├── default
        │   ├── my-view.js
        ├── home
        └── view-manifest.json
```

So image.png is nowhere to be found there.

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You have a typo `<div id="container"` Should be `<div id="container">`. Is this the cause of your problem?

Comment: No, i guess not. I just had a bunch of other stuff in there thats not really relevant for the question. The problem is that when i use "polymer build" command on application level only "polymer-image.js" gets included in my build and not the image or the image folder

Comment: Try removing `"/images/**/*"` from the sources, leave only `"images/**/*"`. Remove both references to `images` in extraDependencies and try building it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't change anything. Does 'polymer build' even care about polymer.json files that are inside folders of sub components?

Comment: Did you ever found a response to this problem?